# Set Javascript Variable From PHP Get Variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page which I have collected two variables, I want to pass these variables to my document ready function. but for some reason.. My alerts for testing are just outputting the line code rather than the result.

just to note the JS script is in another file which is linked to the page.

**PHP**

```
<?php 

$cardid = test;
$custid = test;

?>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var custid = '<?php echo($custid); ?>';
   var cardid = '<?php echo($cardid); ?>';

   alert(custid);
   alert(cardid);
});
```

Comment: the JS script file, does it end with .php ?

Comment: no .js and is linked to the .php page but called at the bottom

Comment: For php to be executed it must be in a .php file.

Comment: In addition, you're outputting strings instead of having the PHP code execute. Neither of your variables are GET variables.

Comment: FYI, echo is not a function. You _can_ still use the `()`s, but simply `<?php echo $custid;?>` is sufficient.

Comment: Well **that** is good community work :)

Comment: BTW: easiest way to debug things like that is to view the source of your file in your browser (since you can see what your PHP generated on the serverside).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your javascript code into a separate php file under script tag:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

       var custid = '<?php echo($custid); ?>';
       var cardid = '<?php echo($cardid); ?>';

       alert(custid);
       alert(cardid);
   })

</script>
```

Include this file in your main php file (using the [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function).
It is not possible to execute php in a separate .js file.

Comment: *Note*: if you **must** maintain your JS inside a .js file, linked to the main file, for code security reasons, then it's not possible to execute PHP code in it.

Comment: You could technically use php inside of it if you set the headers appropiately

Comment: @Jay has a point, consider improving your answer approaching all OP failures.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Can you to edit my answer to be correct?

Comment: @JayBlanchard that's not true. the PHP tags in a PHP file are "stronger" than anything else. in a PHP file this would work.

Comment: @AlanMachado again, Jay's statement is not true. PHP tags in a PHP file are "stronger" than quotation marks. I even tested this right now.

Comment: Just tested @low_rents with mixed results. You're right - in a PHP file the PHP was interpreted much as it would be as if it were embedded in any HTML file.

Comment: I didn't test it @low_rents, just sounded right... thanks for the heads up! But even then, there are still some details that could be added to the answer.

Comment: The only 'edit' to be made here would be to make this a PHP file and include it in the other file @makadlcik

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ok, I will take a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

you aren't assigning anything to your PHP variables:

```
$cardid = test;
$custid = test;
```

a value which isn't numeric and isn't in between quotation marks is considered a constant in PHP. and the constant `test` most likely has no value in your PHP environment.

you wanted to assign a string, i guess, so don't forget the quotation marks:

```
$cardid = "test";
$custid = "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong concept.
Your JS is not parsed by PHP, so your approach will not work.
Lets make it work:

You have to give the Variables to JS with one trick: Write it into the HTML in a script-tag, then you can access them in your JS.

Lets assume, you produce a HTML like this in your PHP:

```
<body>
 <div>Hello World</div>
</body>
```

Now, write the variables for you JS into it, here is a simple approach:

```
echo "<script>var myVar1='".$_GET['var1']."';</script>\n";
echo "<body>\n";
echo "  <div>Hello World</div>\n";
echo "</body>\n";
```

Okay, *very* simple, do not do it like this in real, but you got the concept?
So, that was the trick to do this.

P.S. The same way, you get $_POST Data to your JS ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using quote to represent string.

```
<?php 

$cardid = 'test';
$custid = 'test';

?>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   var custid = '<?php echo($custid); ?>';
   var cardid = '<?php echo($cardid); ?>';

   alert(custid);
   alert(cardid);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP code will only be run in files ending with `.php`.  Your`.js` file is loaded directly and not subject to PHP processing.  If you wish to assign values from PHP variables to javascript variables you will need to do so in a script block in your `.php` file.

For example if you add this to your `.php` file -

```
<script type="javascript">
  var custid = '<?php echo $custid; ?>';
  var cardid = '<?php echo $cardid; ?>';
</script>
```

Then in your `.js` file shold look like -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert(custid);
   alert(cardid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is of course possible to run PHP in a .js file. As in the case of running PHP as an Apache module, you can add whatever extensions you want Apache to recognize as PHP scripts, such as:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm .js
```

starting with php5.3 you could probably get issues so you can try also:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php7 .php .html .htm .js
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm .js
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .html .htm .js
```

if you still get issues use a 301 redirect or a rewrite rule in your .htaccess, like this for example:

```
Redirect 301 "^(.*)/dir/example.js$" "http://www.domain.de/dir/example.php" [NC,L,QSA]
```

if you are on lighttpd go to /etc/lighttpd.conf or on Windoze C:\lighttpd\etc\lighttpd.conf, uncomment the "mod_cgi" line and add this line:

```
cgi.assign = ( ".js" => "c:/php/php-cgi.exe" )
```

don't give up just because someone say to you "you can't do this or that" ;-)